# Merging Database Tables Using Views and Unions and Innerjoin Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I want have a global view of all the data in multiple databases.  Each database contains the same tables.

```
Database: DB1
Table: Companies
CompanyID      CompanyName
---------------------------------
1              Disney
2              Marvel
3              DC

Table: Employees
Employee ID    CompanyID      CompanyName      EmployeeName
------------------------------------------------------------
1              1              Disney           Donald Duck
2              1              Disney           Mickey Mouse
3              2              Marvel           Spiderman
4              2              Marvel           Captain America
5              3              DC               Superman
6              3              DC               Batman

Database: DB2
Table: Companies
CompanyID      CompanyName
---------------------------------
1              Warner Brothers
2              Hanna Barbera

Table: Employees
Employee ID    CompanyID      CompanyName      EmployeeName
------------------------------------------------------------
1              1              Warner Brothers  Wolverine
2              1              Warner Brothers  Cyclops
3              2              Hanna Barbera    Fred Flinstone
4              2              Hanna Barbera    Barney Rubble
```

I created the following Views in Database, DB1:

```
CREATE VIEW [CompaniesView]
as
select *
from [Companies] A
union all
select *
from DB2.dbo.[Companies] B

CREATE VIEW [EmployeesView]
as
select *
from [Employees] A
union all
select *
from DB2.dbo.[Employees] B
```

Executing the views work as expected.  My problem is when I join the 2 views.

```
select C.CompanyName, E.CompanyName, E.EmployeeName 
  from CompaniesView as C
  join EmployeesView as E 
    on C.CompanyID = E.CompanyID
```

Here are the results:

```
CompanyName       CompanyName      EmployeeName
------------------------------------------------------------
Disney            Disney           Donald Duck
Disney            Disney           Mickey Mouse
Warner Brothers   Warner Brothers  Wolverine
Warner Brothers   Warner Brothers  Cyclops
Marvel            Marvel           Spiderman
Marvel            Marvel           Captain America
Hanna Barbera     Hanna Barbera    Fred Flinstone
Hanna Barbera     Hanna Barbera    Barney Rubble
DC                DC               Superman
DC                DC               Batman
Warner Brothers   Disney           Donald Duck
Warner Brothers   Disney           Mickey Mouse
Warner Brothers   Warner Brothers  Wolverine
Warner Brothers   Warner Brothers  Cyclops
Hanna Barbera     Marvel           Spiderman
Hanna Barbera     Marvel           Captain America
Hanna Barbera     Hanna Barbera    Fred Flinstone
Hanna Barbera     Hanna Barbera    Barney Rubble
```

These are the results I want:

```
CompanyName       CompanyName      EmployeeName
------------------------------------------------------------
Disney            Disney           Donald Duck
Disney            Disney           Mickey Mouse
Warner Brothers   Warner Brothers  Wolverine
Warner Brothers   Warner Brothers  Cyclops
Marvel            Marvel           Spiderman
Marvel            Marvel           Captain America
Hanna Barbera     Hanna Barbera    Fred Flinstone
Hanna Barbera     Hanna Barbera    Barney Rubble
DC                DC               Superman
DC                DC               Batman
```

How can I get this to work using using Views only?

Comment: Why are you repeating CompanyName in the Employee table?  That violates 3NF.

Answer (score 4):

You can include a database identifier in the views and in the query joins.

```
create view dbo.CompaniesView
as
select 1 as DatabaseID, CompanyID, CompanyName
from DB1.dbo.Companies
union all
select 2 as DatabaseID, CompanyID, CompanyName
from DB2.dbo.Companies
GO

create view dbo.EmployeesView
as
select 1 as DatabaseID, Employee ID, CompanyID, CompanyName, EmployeeName
from DB1.dbo.Employees
union all
select 2 as DatabaseID, Employee ID, CompanyID, CompanyName, EmployeeName
from DB2.dbo.Employees
GO

select E.DatabaseID, C.CompanyName, E.CompanyName, E.EmployeeName 
from CompaniesView as C
join EmployeesView as E 
    on C.DatabaseID = E.DatabaseID
    and C.CompanyID = E.CompanyID
```

Comment: Now this solutions looks very promising.  I would have to try this and see what the performance looks like.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the DB is confused by the duplicate CompanyID values for different company names.

This query should get you the result you want:

```
select C.CompanyName, E.CompanyName, E.EmployeeName from CompaniesView as C
inner join EmployeesView as E on C.CompanyID = E.CompanyID and C.CompanyName = E.CompanyName
```

Note the added "and C.CompanyName = E.CompanyName" on the end.

I also want to note that you may want to consider getting rid of the company name columns in the employees tables and put a foreign key on the company ID columns in the employees tables referencing the companies tables. Unless you already have keys or other tools in place, you're open to losing data integrity as you have it laid out here.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a foreign key, Company ID, on Employees table form the Companies table.  What you proposed would work if I CompanyName was a foreign key.  At this point, I'm not guaranteed that Company Name would match one to one in both Tables.  Only thing I'm guaranteed is the Company ID.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you would get the result you are looking for by adding the company name in the mix. But the thought of having an ID that you consider as a primary key reference(CompanyId,EmployeeId) being duplicated and pointing to different companies/employees is just not sitting well with me. This could cause a lot of confusion and erroneous code in future. If it were me I would do away with the companyId and EmployeeId in the view and build a CompanyReference and EmployeeReference that could be a manufactured key Like - DBName+CAST(CompanyId as nVarchar). This way you are avoiding any assumptions on part of the primarykeys/foreign keys.

*Disclaimer - I know it would affect performance and my suggestion was just what it is a suggestion which might lead to the right track

Comment: I would have to give this a little more thought.